# Tensorflow flow testing error on windows 7 pc

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I've installed Tensorflow on my Windows PC however, it's giving me below error when I tried to test it with basic codes mentioned on "tensorflow.org'.

Error message is -

```
import tensorflow as tf

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Please help me to figure out this problem
Thank you.﻿

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: I've written a script that helps diagnose installation issues for TensorFlow on Windows: https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c  ... if it doesn't come up with any suggestions, then there may be a bug.